# get numbers in string separated by semi-colon and calculate average jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I've got a string like so:

"45; 32; 31; 54"

I want to take these 4 numbers out of the string, then add them all together and divide by the  number of numbers in the string in order to get the average.

How would I do this? There may be only 1 number (thus no need to average it), or there may be 10 numbers, I have no way of knowing how many numbers there will be in each one, except to say there will always be at least 1 number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var str = "45; 32; 31; 54";
var arr = str.split(';'); //split into array
console.log(arr);

var sum = arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return +a + +b }); //Calculate sum
var avg = sum / arr.length; // Calculate avg
console.log(avg);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UcsX6/)

Note: Used `+Variable` to convert variable to number

Comment: I like it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

here is :

```
var s="45;32;31;54";
var s_array=s.split(';');
var sum=0;
var avarage=0;
for(var i =0;i<s_array.length;i++){

  sum+=parseInt(s_array[i]); 
}
avarage=sum/s_array.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is :

```
var data = "45; 32; 31; 54"; //select the string
var arr = data.split('; '); //split the string
var sum = 0;

$.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
    sum += parseFloat(value);
});

var avg = sum / (arr.length);
console.log(avg)
```

Steps :
1. Define variable of string
2. Split it in to array.
3. Parse through array and add all the elements
4. Calculate Average :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this kind of tasks, and you can do everything in one line, using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var str = "45; 32; 31; 54";

var average = str.split("; ").reduce(function(avg, number, index) {
   return +avg + (number - avg) / (index + 1)
});
```

This is an incremental average, that is also useful if you have a lot of numbers and/or big numbers, so with regular averaging you could end up in overflow while you summing up the elements, this approach reduce that risk.

For the browser doesn't support `reduce` the documentation above provides a shim – nowadays modern browsers support ES5, and for older browsers this kind of shim should be a must-have.